# How can we call availity Claim Eligibility check URL

Tags: php, curl, soap

Currently i am using the following code to call the URL to check eligibility.But it always returns "**user ID () and password does not match**" error.I double checked the user name and password with the server team .They said user name and password are correct.Is there any mistake with my code.

```
<?php
  $soap_request  = file_get_contents('../Sample_2011_PDI_Request.xml');  
  $header = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",     
    "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
  );

  $soap_do = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "https://qa-apps.availity.com/availity/B2BHCTransactionServlet" );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        20);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
 $res = curl_exec($soap_do);
  if($res === false) {
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
  } else {
    curl_close($soap_do);
    var_dump($res);
  }
?>
```

The data that i am sending to the availity is given bellow(Sample_2011_PDI_Request.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:core2="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="false">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1538899148">
<wsse:Username>MYUSERNAME</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">MYPASSWORD</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<ns1:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest xmlns:ns1="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/CORERule2.2.0.xsd">
<PayloadType>X12_270_Request_005010X279A1</PayloadType>
<ProcessingMode>RealTime</ProcessingMode>
<PayloadID>010454917</PayloadID>
<TimeStamp>2015-03-24T09:22:06-5:00</TimeStamp>
<SenderID>MYSenderID</SenderID>
<ReceiverID>AVAILITY</ReceiverID>
<CORERuleVersion>2.2.0</CORERuleVersion>
<Payload>
<![CDATA[ISA*03*MYUSERNAME*01*MYPASSWORD*ZZ*MYSenderID*01*030240928      *090508*0003*^*00501*917753427*0*P*:~
GS*HS*AV01101957*030240928*20090508*0003*917753427*X*005010X279A1~
ST*270*000000001*005010X279A1~
BHT*0022*13*917753427*20090508*000350~
HL*1**20*1~
NM1*PR*2*HUMANA*****PI*61101~
HL*2*1*21*1~
NM1*1P*2*SAMPLE PROVIDER*****XX*1234567893~
HL*3*2*22*0~
TRN*1*123456789012345678*9AB0A0A0A0~
NM1*IL*1*DOE*JOHN****MI*ABCD12345678~
DMG*D8*19610107*M~
DTP*291*D8*20090508~
EQ*30~
SE*13*000000001~
GE*1*917753427~
IEA*1*917753427~]]>
</Payload>
</ns1:COREEnvelopeRealTimeRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Where you are using `username` and `password` in this code?

Comment: In the XML file"Sample_2011_PDI_Request.xml"